# Ubuntu 16.04 Minecraft Doesn't Run

Tags: 16.04, minecraft

I'm having some trouble running Minecraft on Ubuntu 16.04. The launcher will open but when I click play, it will close the launcher without opening the game. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Oracle version 9, this will happen.  If you install the Oracle Version 8, it will not close the launcher, and you will be presented with the error everyone else on 16.04+ is getting:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class net.minecraft.client.main.Main
```

From other questions/answers here, this isn't limited to just Ubuntu, but Mint as well.

EDIT:

If you want to just play, go to Edit Profile on the launch screen, and check **Enable experimental development versions ("Snapshots")**, **Save Profile**, and make sure that the use version **Use Latest Version** is selected in the drop down.

You will be able to play at least, even if it's not the latest stable.